# UIView controller containing toolbar and UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm currently creating an ipad application.
the idea is to have a toolbar at the top and a tabbar at the bottom.
The toolbar has to be visible on all tabs, so it won't disappear.
I was thinking about having a UIViewController as the main view and put the tool bar in there.
Then adding the uitabbarcontroller to that main view controller, but i'm not sure how to do that.
At the moment i have my tabbarcontroller as the main view and added the toolbar to every tab.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tab Bar Controller should be at the root.  What you can do is create a method that returns a propertly configured toolbar & add it to each of the view controller's viewDidLoad (either by using a category method, inheriting a common UIViewController subclass, or simply via a C-style factory method.

This way your hierarchy isn't flipped, and the tab bar is at the root like it should be.